# modify mysql php query results prior to returning

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables

I have a database with a table containing user information.

User table:
id
username
password

When the user table is created, I also create a table for each user named after the id.
id table:
req_id (auto increments)
vendor
authorized

I am querying the user table and also want to query the newest req_id for each user and return the results.  I have to append each row of the results with the users req_id

I have the following code but am not sure on how add the req_id to each row and return the results.

```
public function getAllUsersInfo() {
    $result = mysql_query("select * FROM users");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $rows[] = $row; 
} 
for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++) { 
        $id = $rows[$i]['id']
    $req_id = mysql_query("select req_id FROM $id ORDER BY req_id DESC LIMIT 1;");
//Need to append the req_id to the row
} 
    return $result; //so should be returning id, username, password, req_id
}
```

Comment: A separate table for each user is a crazy schema. Why not just a table whose primary key is `user_id, req_id`, or a relation table that links the user table and the request table?

Comment: Indeed.  This schema is bad. Change it. Make a user_req table that relates users to reqs.

Comment: And don't use deprecated connection methods :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

public function getAllUsersInfo() {
    $result = mysql_query("select * FROM users");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $rows[] = $row; 
    } 
    for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++) { 
        $id = $rows[$i]['id'];
        $req_result = mysql_query("select req_id FROM $id ORDER BY req_id DESC LIMIT 1;");
        $req_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req_result);
        $rows[$i]['req_id'] = $req_row['req_id']; // Add the req_id to the row
    } 
    return $rows;
}
```